# "Move" characters from end of field to beginning

Tags: mysql

This is perhaps a fairly unique usage case, but I have a large (60,000 records) table which I need to do some spring cleaning on.

The main thing I need to do is normalise the naming convention of my items. Some are **The Matrix**, and some are **Matrix, The**. Some are even **Matrix, The (15)**.

I know how to REMOVE the string ", The" - but what I would like to do is move the word to the beginning and remove the comma and space. I've done a few hundred manually but it's tedious.

Any ideas? I have a backup!

Answer (score 1):

You mean you have the value "Matrix, The" in a column, on a bunch of records, and would like to change those to "The Matrix"?  If so, why  not just do

```
update mytable set title = "The Matrix" where title = "Matrix, The";
```

or more general, for any title where ", The" occurs at the end

```
update mytable set title = CONCAT("The ", LEFT(title, LENGTH(title) - 5)) where right(title, 5) = ", The";
```

or even more general, for any title with a comma in it

```
update mytable set title = CONCAT(RIGHT(title, LENGTH(title)-LOCATE(", ", title) - 1), " ", LEFT(title, LOCATE(", ", title) - 1)) where LOCATE(", ", title) > 0;
```

I would run that last one as a select first, just to visually confirm the changes:

```
select title, CONCAT(RIGHT(title, LENGTH(title)-LOCATE(", ", title) - 1), LEFT(title, LOCATE(", ", title) - 1)) from mytable where LOCATE(", ", title) > 0;
```

Comment: This can even be handled more general to process _all_ entries holding a comma in that column.

Comment: yes -  update mytable set title = CONCAT("The ", LEFT(title, LENGTH(title) - 5)) where right(title, 5) = ", The";

Comment: Great work. The first example works perfectly for all titles *ending* in ", The" though doesn't work if there are other characters after such as the **Matrix, The (15)** example.

Your third example gives results like this:

`Operative, The:  No One Lives Forever` becomes `, The:  No One Lives ForeverOperative`

Comment: I have made a small correction to the third example to get rid of the comma at the beginning, but I would not be able to give you a solution that will cover every case you have.  This should point the way, though, and you will have to adjust it to cover different cases.  If there are other characters like the colon ":" that separate the title, you will have to do a similar break for that, kind of like I have done with the comma.